# Initialize min variable when dealing with big values in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have some code where I need to find minimum of something.

So I do:

```
min_val = np.inf 
for e in elements:
    if e<min_val:
        min_val = e
```

The problem with that is that some of my elements are REALLY big, and the if statement returns False.

For example:

```
np.inf > 1e999
>>> False
```

Now I could do something like

```
min_val = elements[0]
```

and afterwards iterate from elements[1], but isn't there a more elegant way of doing this (This will require me to do further checkings, like if elements is not empty, if elements[0] is not `inf` etc.).

Isn't there a **real** inf in python (which should simply return True to any "inf>finite number" condition?).

Now, this question is **not** duplicate to the fact that 1e999==np.inf.
The "duplicate" question *explains* the problem. Now I need to resolve it.

**To put it simple**

How do I find the minimum of [1e999, 1e310]?

Comment: What happens with `math.inf`?

Comment: @DavidS - no, this just explains the problem...

Comment: perhaps you can tell us more about your original question of finding minimum. There seems to exist better ways to find minimums. There are built-in functions for it. For example, if your object is an array, you can use `min_val = elements.min()`

Comment: @roganjosh - exactly the same as np.inf

Comment: As far as I understand it python support arbitrarily big integers, so if your problem can be solved with (reduced to) integers only then you are good to go.

Example:
```
#Using Floats
np.inf > 1e999 
False

#Using Integers
np.inf > 10**999
True
```

Answer (score 1):

np.inf is a real inf, but any float larger than 1e308 is going to be treated like infinity. Therefore you're testing if np.inf > np.inf, and it treats it as not greater than itself (perhaps mathematically it doesnt completely make sense).

One solution when it comes to the comparison is to use np.inf >= 1e999   will return True.

Other solution is to use np.min function to find a minimum of an array.

Comment: np.min([1e999,1e998])
Out[1]: inf

Comment: @binyamineven so? You've exceeded the maximum value of a 64-bit float so it's no less sensible than any other output

Comment: So? So I want to find the minimum. This is the whole question.

Comment: You can't find the minimum of numbers that a computer can't even comprehend. You'd have to try 128 bit or something (I'm not sure numpy will stretch)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :**

From the comments below, I understand your question to be **"How do I work with numbers greater than 1e309"**.

I would advise you to take a look at
[this question on quora](https://www.quora.com/What-language-has-the-best-tools-for-dealing-with-extremely-large-numbers).

It gives different solution to your problem.

---

Else, your problem is impossible to solve using only python and "classic" numbers.

```
import numpy as np
a = 1e999
a == np.inf
>>> True
```

The problem is that all number above `1e309` (roughly) are equals to `np.inf`

Comment: so lets suppose my array is [1e310, 1e999] - It will return 1e999 as minimum.

Comment: 1e999 doesn't exist, neither does 1e310. The number in any computer are stored in binary variables encoded on a given number of bits. That means there is a maximum to the number the sytem can use. In our case, this maximum is somewhere between 1e308 and 1e309, meaning that every number greater than this IS infinity.

Comment: @BinyaminEven I think the problem lies under the understanding of what a computer considers as a float and what is this data type's limits. I would suggest searching for information on float to get a better realization of computer vs. pure math numbers.

Comment: If your list only contains numbers greater than 1e309, your minimum IS infinity.

Comment: Man... I need the minmum. To explain that 1e309 is infinity doesn't help me. If you have an answer please share it.

Comment: I edited my answer, it should give you some hint on how to solve your problem.